# Is it possible to override a method of one class, in another class?

Tags: java, string, oop, calendar, tostring

Is it possible to override a toString() method in another class through another class, so you don't have to rewrite a whole class just so you can rewrite one method? For example, I want to rewrite the toString() method in the Calendar class with this segment of code:

```
public String toString() {
    Date date = getTime();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

so that it will return something like,

```
17/03/2019
```

instead of a barely readable String like,

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1552855726815,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/New_York",offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=235,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/New_York,offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2019,MONTH=2,WEEK_OF_YEAR=12,WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_MONTH=17,DAY_OF_YEAR=76,DAY_OF_WEEK=1,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=1,HOUR=4,HOUR_OF_DAY=16,MINUTE=48,SECOND=46,MILLISECOND=815,ZONE_OFFSET=-18000000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]
```

If not, can I have some suggestions on how I can write a method to accomplish something similar to this?

Comment: You don't have to rewrite a whole class just to override one method. But why do you need a override of `toString()`? Why not have a new method that does what you want? The purpose of the `toString()` method in Java is to have a way to textually represent the object. If you overwrite it, you will eliminate it's intended purpose.

Comment: It's possible by just extending the desired class. But doing so just to override a helper method like `toString()` is likely not necessary. I suspect there's a better way to accomplish what you're trying to do. Why not just write a method that converts the string into a format you want?

Comment: Add a Calendar argument to your toString() method, and call getTime on this Calendar. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html. Also, please stop using Calendar and Date. They are obsolete. Use the classes from the java.time package.

Comment: That looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). What is the context and what you *really* want to accomplish?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`, `GregorianCalendar`, `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the last in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: My gut feeling is you don’t want to use overriding for this particular purpose, but to answer your question directly: yes, in a subclass of `GregorianCalendar` you can.

Answer (score 2):

Allow me to suggest a different approach.

Separate your model and business logic from your user interface. Dates belong in your model. String representations of dates belong in the interface.

In your model use `LocalDate` for dates. Under no circumstances resort to the old `Calendar`, `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated.

In your interface use a `DateTimeFormatter` for formatting the `LocalDate` from the model into a string suitable for the user. Prefer to use the built-in localized formats rather than building your own from a format pattern string.

Sometimes it’s good to have an object with a `toString` method that gives a string suitable for presentation. This could for example be the case if we want to present our objects in a `JList`. In this case wrap your business objects in UI objects, for example like this:

```
public class PresentableDate {

    private static final DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT)
            .withLocale(Locale.CANADA_FRENCH);

    LocalDate date;

    public PresentableDate(LocalDate date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return date.format(dateFormatter);
    }

}
```

Only please keep this class in your UI code. If for example the model needs a selected date, take the `LocalDate` out of the `PresentableDate` and pass only the `LocalDate` back to the model. `PresentableDate`is akin to the *decorator* that Louis Wasserman suggested [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55211852/is-it-possible-to-override-a-method-of-one-class-in-another-class/55220754#comment97160789_55211910). It follows the *Composition over inheritance* principle.

And just to demonstrate that the `toString`method works:

```
    System.out.println(new PresentableDate(LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("America/Toronto"))));
```

Output:

> 19-03-18

**Links**

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Composition over inheritance on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could accomplish a different 'toString' function for the GregorianCalendar by extending GregorianCalendar.java in a subclass called, in this example, CoolGregorianCalendar.

Extending the class will allow you to Override the Object#toString method and supply whatever String you want.

Object#toString is conventionally used to concisely and informatively represent an object in an easy to read fashion. It's recommended that "all subclasses override this method."

Here's the code for the CoolGregorianCalendar.java

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class CoolGregorianCalendar extends GregorianCalendar {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        Date date = getTime();
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }

}
```

Based on the fact that it's meant to uniquely identify that object, two objects could be created at the same time and yield the same toString representation - but that's an issue for you to pursue :)

You can read up further on inheritance from oracle's documentation over @ https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

and you can also read further about overriding Object#toString over at
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29

Comment: @boblarry No, this is not a good idea or a good habit to get into.

Comment: @Zephyr I welcome an alternative solution to making a class' method do something else without using inheritance other than using a separate name, which isn't exactly what OP asked for.

Comment: Please don't use "dd/MM/yyyy" as it is ambiguous and therefore not much better than the "barely readable" original.  If you are going to use numeric notation, follow the ISO-8601 standard and keep the larger units to the left as you do with other numeric representations.

Comment: @nathan3882 trying to modify the behavior of other classes in general isn't a good habit to get into, no matter how you do it.  It may satisfy the OP's specified constraints, but it may be that any answer satisfying those constraints is still "a bad habit to get into."  (A separate decorator class, or a `static String dateToString(Date)`, would probably be better solutions as far as good coding practice.)